# PHP - other alternatives to many if/else nested checks?

Tags: php, if-statement, controls, structure

I have an if/else structure.

It first checks to see the value of stage. I have illustrated for you the logic structure to 3 level deep, but it could go 10... with each move from one stage to the next we are doubling the number of checks.

stage has 2 branchings

next stage check has has 4

the next stage has 8

and so on...

For each stage (an identifier), I am calling some functions. **The value of those functions is then passed along down to the next if/else (it checks for the value pulled from the functions) and perform the next calculation.**

**The idea is that the user enters the first if/else, then it goes down that branch. A value is carried down all along. Is there a way to carry a value down along, and proceed differently once the value of a flag ("stage" in this case) changes?**

- Inside stage=**1** loop have another if/else loop, called stage.

  - If stage=1 then proceed to perform functions a,b,c.

    - If stage=1 then proceed to perform functions a,b,c.

      - If stage=1 then proceed to perform functions a,b,c.
      - If stage=0, proceed and do something else.
    - If stage=0, proceed and do something else.

      - If stage=1 then proceed to perform functions a,b,c.
      - If stage=0, proceed and do something else.
  - If stage=0, proceed and do something else.

    - If stage=1 then proceed to perform functions a,b,c.

      - If stage=1 then proceed to perform functions a,b,c.
      - If stage=0, proceed and do something else.
    - If stage=0, proceed and do something else.

      - If stage=1 then proceed to perform functions a,b,c.
      - If stage=0, proceed and do something else.

and then for the first stage=0 check, the same logic repeats:

- Inside stage=**0** loop have another if/else loop, called stage.

  - If stage=1 then proceed to perform functions a,b,c.

    - If stage=1 then proceed to perform functions a,b,c.

      - If stage=1 then proceed to perform functions a,b,c.
      - If stage=0, proceed and do something else.
    - If stage=0, proceed and do something else.

      - If stage=1 then proceed to perform functions a,b,c.
      - If stage=0, proceed and do something else.
  - If stage=0, proceed and do something else.

    - If stage=1 then proceed to perform functions a,b,c.

      - If stage=1 then proceed to perform functions a,b,c.
      - If stage=0, proceed and do something else.
    - If stage=0, proceed and do something else.

      - If stage=1 then proceed to perform functions a,b,c.
      - If stage=0, proceed and do something else.

How would one go about in replicating the same logic without having to write so many if/else checks?

Comment: I think you should rethink your logic. Among other things, "stages" may not be the appropriate abstraction.

Comment: also, if/else is not a loop.

Comment: Perhaps you can tell us the idea behind the if/else structure. What do you want to achieve with this?

Comment: I was expecting some different approach in answers...

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking something like:

```
completed = "0";

if($function_flag=="0") { $data = $original_data; }

do
    {
    $data = $data_from_function;

    if($stage=="0") {
       ...call function A...    
       if($function_flag=="1") { completed = "1"; }  
       }
   if($stage=="1") {
       ...call function B...    
       if($function_flag=="1") { completed = "1"; }  
       }
   }
   while($completed=="0")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure if this answers your question, but the above can be condensed into

```
if (stage == 1 || stage == 0) { // really necessary? only if stage can have other values
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (stage == 1) {
            functionA();
            functionB();
            functionC();
        }
        else {
            somethingElse();
        }
    }
}
```